# SIGSEGV with JNI call converting jlong to long

Tags: java, c, linux, segmentation-fault, java-native-interface

I'm working with JNI to call from my Java application an external C library given by a software editor to access/write datas from their application.

I get SIGSEGV fatal error with some calls and I can't found out why.
Here the error log given by the JVM :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1b357729e0, pid=18693, tid=139752817592064
#
# JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007f1b357729e0
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f1b1001d000):  JavaThread "http-bio-10.70.4.12-10767-exec-12" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=18888, stack(0x00007f1abcfc8000,0x00007f1abd0c9000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00007f1b357729e0

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f1b35dfd990, RBX=0x000000000000000b, RCX=0x000000000000000b,     RDX=0x00007f1ac1d3d650
RSP=0x00007f1abd0c5178, RBP=0x00007f1abd0c51a0, RSI=0x000000000000000b, RDI=0x00007f1ac1d3d650
R8 =0x00007f1b506c9278, R9 =0x00007f1b1001e328, R10=0x00007f1b45011894, R11=0x00007f1b503b2d10
R12=0x00007f1ac1d3d650, R13=0x00000000e2de9358, R14=0x00007f1abd0c5260, R15=0x00007f1b1001d000
RIP=0x00007f1b357729e0, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000014
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f1abd0c5178)
0x00007f1abd0c5178:   00007f1b35beed30 00007f1b1001d000
...
0x00007f1abd0c5358:   00007f1abd0c5358 00000000e321a20a
0x00007f1abd0c5368:   00007f1abd0c5440 00000000e4699898 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f1b357729e0)
0x00007f1b357729c0:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack,     instructions near pc), id 0xb]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f1b35dfd990: s_fnAmGetFieldLongValue+0 in /app/rct/ASK4IT/2/tomcat7/installedApps/ask4itWeb.war/WEB-INF/dll/HP/AssetManager/x64/libamapijni.so at 0x00007f1b35be5000
RBX=0x000000000000000b is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000000000000b is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f1ac1d3d650 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f1abd0c5178 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f1b1001d000
RBP=0x00007f1abd0c51a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f1b1001d000
RSI=0x000000000000000b is an unknown value
RDI=0x00007f1ac1d3d650 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f1b506c9278: <offset 0xaa2278> in /tech/java/oracle/jdk-1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f1b4fc27000
R9 =0x00007f1b1001e328 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007f1b45011894 is an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native_synchronized)  [0x00007f1b450114c0, 0x00007f1b45011e80]  2496 bytes
R11=0x00007f1b503b2d10: <offset 0x78bd10> in /tech/java/oracle/jdk-1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f1b4fc27000
R12=0x00007f1ac1d3d650 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000e2de9358 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x00007f1abd0c5260 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f1b1001d000
R15=0x00007f1b1001d000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007f1abcfc8000,0x00007f1abd0c9000],  sp=0x00007f1abd0c5178,  free space=1012k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00007f1b357729e0
j  com.afkl.ask4it.amapi.JNI.Base.AmGetFieldLongValue(JJ)J+0

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.afkl.ask4it.amapi.JNI.Base.AmGetFieldLongValue(JJ)J+0
J  com.afklm.askfourit.query.QueryUtil.getFieldValue(JJJLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j      com.afklm.askfourit.dao.Ask4ItModelDAO.createAsk4itModelBean(JJ)Lcom/afklm/askfourit/entity/Ask4ItModel;+602
...
```

As you can see in the stack, the method causing the crash is this one :

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_afkl_ask4it_amapi_JNI_Base_AmGetFieldLongValue(JNIEnv * env, jclass c, jlong jlhQuery, jlong jiPos)
{
  long lFieldVal = AmGetFieldLongValue(jl2c(jlhQuery), jl2c(jiPos));
  if(fhLog)
    amapi_JNI_log("AmGetFieldLongValue","object %ld pos %ld : %ld",jl2c(jlhQuery), jl2c(jiPos),lFieldVal);
  return lFieldVal;
}
```

This function just do a call to the native function AmGetFieldLongValue of the external library. It is just a translation to allow Java to call it, without doing anything else than passing argument and retrieve results.

The only thing I can think causing the SIGSEGV is the call to jl2c to convert jlong to long, defined as :

```
#define jl2c(_jl) ((long)(_jl))
```

Or the returned value lFieldVal defined in this function as a long whereas the method returns a jlong.

I expect thoses convertions causing the trouble because I read somewhere that "passing char* where a jstring is needed could crash the JVM".
I had many JVM crashes because of this before, but I rewrote this JNI to stop doing this, and pass jbyteArray where jstring were used, and then use this code to convert it as a char* :

```
jsize lengthTable = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jstrTable);
jbyte* jByteStrTable = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, jstrTable, 0);
char* pszTable = malloc(lengthTable + 1);
memcpy(pszTable, jByteStrTable, lengthTable);
pszTable[lengthTable] = '\0';
```

Now it seems I have no more crashes on this functions, so I hope this code to correct my previous problem, but now it seems I have the same kind of problems with others types conversions.

But I can't found out what's wrong with it. 
I read a jlong is a 64bit signed integer and a cast from a jlong to an long could cause this kind of error if the long is defined as a 32bit integer but I don't know how to securise the cast, or something else.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try this jlong lFieldVal = (jlong)AmGetFieldLongValue(jl2c(jlhQuery), jl2c(jiPos));

Comment: Your crash file says that you're on 64 bit Linux, so `long` should be 8 bytes, exactly the same as `jlong`. Casting cannot be your problem here. Most reliable way to find out what really fails: attach a native debugger to your process, set a breakpoint, then call your method.